# find -exec grep {} \; egrep -v string \; # the command chain brakes

Tags: grep, find, exec, egrep

I'm playing with find command to see how it behaves and I'm a bit lost.

First bit is fine :

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -exec grep -l abc {} \;
grep: .: Is a directory
./file2.pdf
./file1
```

Then I try to exclude the .pdf file  by chaining another egrep command but I fail.

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -exec grep -l abc {} \; -exec egrep -vl '*.pdf' {} \;
grep: .: Is a directory
./file2.pdf
./file2.pdf
./file1
./file1
```

Why it doesn't exclude the .pdf file and also prints the result two times ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`egrep -vl '*.pdf' some_file` examines the file *content*, not name.

The right way to exclude names with `find` is to negate (`!`) a proper `-name` (or `-iname` if available) expression. Example:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 ! -name '*.pdf' -exec grep -l abc {} \;
```

---

Each result was printed twice because after the first `grep` printed it and returned success, the second one (`egrep`) apparently didn't find `*.pdf` (interpreted as an extended regular expression) in the respective file content and thus (mind the `-v`) printed the same name.

Note `-exec` is also a test. In your case if the first `-exec` reports failure then the second `-exec` will not be triggered. The first `-exec` will report failure if its `grep` reports failure. And the `grep` will report failure if it doesn't find the pattern in the file. This means any file that is not printed by the first `grep` cannot be printed by the second one (`egrep`) because the second one doesn't even run for the file.

---

Another way to exclude `.pdf` files is to filter the *output* of your first `find` (which in your case is in fact the output of `grep`s; your `find` prints nothing by itself). Like this:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -exec grep -l abc {} \; | grep -iv '\.pdf$'
```

But if any path returned by `find` is multi-line (i.e. if it includes newlines; filenames in Linux can) then the added `grep` will perceive each line separately anyway, as if the lines referred to more than one file; and you will get unexpected results. Therefore testing inside `find` (`-name …`) is better.